# 'Join columns must be present in data' error

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join

I am having this weird issue.

The following code works:

```
Jakarta_Covid <- left_join(DKI_Jakarta, Covid_DF,
                          by = c("Sub_District" = "Sub_District"))
```

However the code chunk below is giving me 'Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `Sub_District`.

```
Jakarta_Death <- Covid_DF %>%
  inner_join(DKI_Jakarta, by=c("Sub_District"="Sub_District")) %>%
  group_by(Sub_District, Month) %>%
  summarise(`Covid Death Per 10,000 Population` = (((sum(Death))/(Total_Population))*10000))

Jakarta_Death  <- Jakarta_Death %>% left_join(DKI_Jakarta, 
                       by=c("Sub_District"="Sub_District"))
```

How can I calculate the 'Covid Death Per 10,000 Population' from two DF and I need the Geometry column in DKI_Jakarta to plot into a map later on.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know about *"trim your code"*, but certainly please provide a MWE with sample data. Also, which join is producing the error?

Comment: Without data, it's difficult to know, but I'd check that, after running the lines ending `summarise(`Covid Death Per 10,000 Population...` there is a column called *Sub_District* in **Jakarta_Death**. You might have to join on the column called, "Covid Death per ..." e.g. by= `c("Sub_District" = "Covid Death per ...")`

Answer (score 0):

`left_join(DKI_Jakarta, Covid_DF, by = c("Sub_District")`
If you have the same column name in both tables just left one in the by=()